# PHP parser of e-mail addresses

Tags: php, parsing, pear, email

Good day, ladies and gentlemans. I'm a newbie in programming and my problem is in creating  a php parser for e-mail addresses.  I need to parse a whole web-site and create a .txt file with e-mails.
So, that is the question. What must I use? Should it be a proper php function *file_get_contents* with any arguments or maybe a PHPparser_Generator from PEAR project?
Any ideas?
P.S.: I would like to remind you not to write the code itself, 'cause I want to do it myself. Just any hint.

Thanks a lot. Best regards, Aen

Comment: Now, why would you want to harvest email addresses from a web site? If you controlled the website, the email addresses would be accessible in user profiles, for example. Sounds spammy to me.

Comment: Smells like a script kiddie project

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, something like.....

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z0-9\._%+!$&*=^|~#%\'`?{}/\-]+@[a-z0-9\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})/i",
   file_get_contents($somefile), $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
foreach ($matches[0] as $addrspec) {
   mail($addrspec, "hello", $msg);
}
```

Comment: The first part of an email address can technically also include an @ :) And you criticised me for only matching ADDR-SPEC so I'd like to see it revised to match the whole email address (now there's a challenge!!!). However, +1 for including the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `file_get_contents` will do it. Assign that to a variable then use preg_match_all to find this expression: `/[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i`. This is a regular expression which matches email addresses.

Comment: Very minor comment - the plus symbol is also valid in the user section of an email address, and has been popularised by it's use in GMail, and some other email providers, as a flag allowing a user to have multiple "virtual" email addresses - ie user+flag1@server.com and user+flag2@server.com would go through the same address.

Comment: Parsing an email address should not be taken lightly: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

Comment: As Lucanos pointed out + should be included as well as other symbols. Look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html and have fun checking out the actual RFC 2822 implementation

Comment: The regex I have used will match the vast majority of email addresses available. You could add a plus in the first set of square brackets if you want to. As for the others mentioned on the linuxjournal article... what percentage of emails take a form like that? 0.0001% would be a pretty good upper limit, I reckon.

Comment: This is a regular expression which matches email addresses. No it's not - both the mailbox and domain validation are wrong (e.g. make$$buy#@somwhere.example.museum) and its contrained to only match an ADDR-SPEC (not an Email address) and the OP seems to be trying to EXTRACT addresses (i.e. why the start/end anchors)

Comment: @symcbean Start/end anchors removed. That's a good point - it was a copy/paste error. As for the others, see my previous comment.